# Print an Attribute of an Object with Iterator in LinkedList - Java

Tags: java

i wanted to print the A (getA()) of the Object Reiter with the iterator, but i don't seem to find anything that works. Could you help somehow please.

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    LinkedList<Reiter> reiter = new LinkedList<Reiter>();

    reiter.add(new Reiter(55));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(30));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(70));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(35));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(60));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(45));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(65));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(40));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(25));
    reiter.add(new Reiter(50));

    Iterator it = reiter.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){

        System.out.print(it.next());
    }

}

class Reiter{

    int a;
    public Reiter(int a){
         this.a = a;
    }
    public int getA(){
         return a;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the raw form of `Iterator`, which will return `Object`s.  You can use the pre-Java 1.5 solution -- cast the returned object to a `Reiter` -- or you can use the generic form of `Iterator`, supplying `Reiter` as a type argument to `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<Reiter> it = reiter.iterator();
```

This will allow you to treat the returned object as a `Reiter` and call `getA()`.

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(it.next().getA());
}
```

Comment: thanks, now it works. i didn't know that i can supply Reiter as a type argument.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop:

```
while(it.hasNext()){
   System.out.print(it.next());
}
```

You need to print it.next().getA();

Simply printing the it.next() will print the object.

So the line should change to

```
System.out.print(it.next().getA());
```

Comment: A raw `Iterator` returns `Object`s, so the `getA()` method won't be available.

Comment: You're right I didn't pay attention to the lack of generics/casting

Comment: Still thanks, it helped a lot. Won't make that mistake again.